# How to make an EditText automatically scroll after an X amount of lines

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have found plenty of answers on how to make scrollable EditText, but none mentions how to make the text scroll after an X amount of lines. In my app i need the text scrolling on its own after 5 lines, otherwise text gets mixed up with icons bellow. So far i have been restricting maxLength to avoid this, but i need to be able to write more characters without worrying that they get mixed up with icons.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/resultText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:ems="30"
    android:maxLength="180"
    android:hint="Input here..."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what i was searching for was:

```
android:lines="5"
```